# How to read matrix elements one by one from file

Tags: c++, file, matrix

This might be an elementary question. I'm new to C++ and I want to implement a huge random matrix which might not fit in the memory. So I think maybe I should write it into a file and read in element by element in a stream.

What I want to check is, if the element is smaller than a threshold. If yes, push the index of the element (i,j) in a stl vector for storage, if no, go to the next element.

Basically I need a couple of lines that write a matrix `AJM` into `matrix.dat`, and then read its element as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        currentElement = "read AJM[i][j] from matrix.txt";
    } 
}
```

So "read AJM[i][j] from matrix.txt" is not clear to me, I guess it's done by iterating the file pointer to some certain position given by i and j, and specify how many bytes to read, right?

Could you show me the C++ code to write `matrix.dat` and read in element one by one knowing its index, so that I avoid storing the whole matrix in the memory?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is the matrix dense or sparse?

Comment: @Emmet It's dense, there is no zero element in it

Comment: it seems that the elements are represented by strings; are the individual strings of uniform length (i.e. all like “3.141592654E+00”) or can they be of different lengths, (i.e. “1.0”, “3.142”, “3.141592534E+00”)?

Comment: @Emmet You are totally right, I shouldn't use txt file, that's just stupid. Let me change to matrix.dat and double type entries.

Comment: as you've twigged, if they're strings of variable length, there's basically no way of mapping a matrix index to a file offset in bytes; you may also lose precision, since the conversion from double to string and back to double doesn't necessarily yield the exact same value back at the end. I'm normally an advocate of human-readable representations in files, but in this case, I think it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be reinventing the wheel here. If the matrix is dense, there are basically two choices: column-major order (for Fortran compatibility) or row-major order (for C multidimensional array compatibility). If the matrix is sparse, then there are a handful of standard formats from which you choose the most appropriate (i.e. different choice for a tridiagonal matrix than a “general” sparse matrix), with CSR/CSC probably being the most widespread “very general” sparse matrix representation. Which in-memory representation you choose will inform the disk-based representation to a large degree. My advice: find and use a library that does what you want, and don't reinvent the wheel.

You have since answered that the matrix is *dense*, and I'm kinda/sorta going to answer the question I think you should have asked, rather than the question you actually asked. If you genuinely have a *huge* matrix (say a billion elements) stored as *text*, you're going to have a really, really bad time, so I'm going to assume that the matrix is stored as doubles to make life a bit easier.

Although there are other possibilities, there are basically two simple on-disk representations for a dense matrix: row-major order and column major order. Having chosen one of these, there are then two choices for taking an index `i,j` and retrieving that value from file, knowing the matrix dimensions. Assume the matrix dimensions are `m` (rows) by `n` (columns), then the offset from the beginning of the matrix corresponding to element `i,j` is (for row-major order):

```
offset = i*n + j
```

or (for column-major order):

```
offset = j*m + i
```

Supposing that the matrix elements are all doubles, then you can `seek()` into the file by this offset, for row-major order doing something like (where `mfs` is a `std::ifstream` attached to the matrix file):

```
double element;
mfs.seekg( (i*n+j)*sizeof(double) );
mfs.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&element), sizeof(double) );
```

Alternatively, on a POSIX-like system, you can use `mmap()` to map the matrix file into memory and use the same rationale to compute the appropriate offset.

Comment: @UpAndAdam: sorry, that sentence doesn't appear to be complete. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: While it could be related, in-memory need not be related to the disk based representation at all. A loading function can deal with that; though in extreme cases or if loading is performance sensitive this is on the right track

Comment: I'm using the library `Eigen` for matrices in the most part of my code. I'm not sure if I can write an `Eigen::MatrixXd AJM` format matrix in the file and access the file just to read a specific AJM(i,j)... All I want to avoid is storing the whole matrix in memory

Comment: @UpAndAdam: yes, it is technically true that the in-memory and on-disk representations don't have to match one-to-one, but in HPC practice there are only two representations for large dense matrices' data on-disk (there may be a simple header with dimensional and type info). There are more esoteric in-memory representations (such as using Morton or Ahnenteufel indexing), but I've never seen one of these on disk.

Comment: @LoganYang: AFAICT, Eigen supports initializing a matrix using the overloaded left-shift operator `<<`, so it seems that all of this may be unnecessary. See [this simple example](http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Eigen-Library-for-Matrix-Algebra-in-C).

Comment: I'd beg to differ. binary, text, xml, json, csv. I've seen it all.  Depends what you are performance testing: loading of the data or actually manipulating the data..  Yes they will have to be row/major or minor, but thats just one aspect. Nonetheless really good mentioning of mmap!

Comment: @UpAndAdam: you've seen *huge, dense* matrices represented as XML and JSON by HPC professionals??? Wow. Glad I'm not you :)

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer and patience. But forgive me, I'm still not clear if I initialized a `Eigen::MatrixXd` matrix and have written it into a file, is there a simpler way to get a specific element from it without reading in the whole matrix? Does `Eigen` have some thing for a simpler file reading option?

Comment: @LoganYang: if the problem here is that the matrix *in Eigen's representation* (say RM) won't fit in memory, then your question, I think, should probably be more like “How do I *extract a `p`x `q` block* from an `m`x `n` matrix stored in a file in row-major order?”, since that appears to be kinda/sorta what you're trying to do, no?

Comment: Yeah, for example I have a Eigen matrix `AJM` stored in file, and I want to extract the submatrix by slicing using two vectors `v1` and `v2` for row and col indices. Just like in Matlab, `AJM(v1,v2)` gives me the submatrix I want. How can I achieve that?

Comment: As long as I have easy access to single elements by index, slicing using `v1` and `v2` like in Matlab is easy. I may just iterate over the elements of the two vectors. What I'm not clear is just getting that single element (i,j) from file. Your answer above does that, right? I'm just wondering if there's an Eigen-format-specific way? No?

Comment: @LoganYang: I'm really not familiar with Eigen, but it appears to have a `Block` class, instances of which are returned from the `block()` method (which takes indices and dimensions of a block) of the `Matrix` class. See [here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=90129) and [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html).

Comment: @Emmet They don't originate from HPC pro's obviously :-\ Remember not every HPC application is entirely isolated in academia / ideal scenarios.  When I did purer HPC stuff absolutely never saw json and xml, but i did see variations where they weren't human readable files.   Maybe its incorrect to truly call it HPC research as opposed to as HPC application as possible :-)

Comment: @Emmet namely one of my favorite formats was binary where it was two 32 bit ints describing dimension (which is nice because you can read it as one 64 bit int and mask it) followed simply by 64 ints.  It sucks to read and manipulate as a human; but you memmap it and all the sudden wam.. or even if you need to read from it periodically its mem-alligned and no string to int conversions, wouldn't work with doubles of course or with switching endianness over and over

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a file you are going to have to decide on an encoding for the data you are storing.

The naive implementation would be to store each element sequentially, doing each row (or column) in order before the next.

No matter what encoding you are using, if it doesn't fit in memory you are going to have to use a file handle that allows repositioning to find the right element. How that exactly works will depend on what you use for loading from the file.

Most often the operation is called `Seek` or some minor variation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I just use the naive implementation, can you show me some code for writing the matrix.txt and reading each element in the way I showed in the question? The easier the better!

Answer (score 0):

How the matrix is read depends on how the matrix is written. Personally, I would start off with writing the matrix by specifying the width and height of the matrix and then write each row as a line. For simplicity I would write the matrix as a text file which could, e.g., look like this:

```
3 4
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

Reading a matrix like this is pretty straight forward:

```
int rows(0), columns(0);
if (in >> rows >> columns) {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix(rows);
    for (int r(0); in && r != rows; ++r) {
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<double>(in), columns,
                    std::back_inserter(matrix[r]));
    }
}
if (!in) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: failed to read matrix\n";
}
```

Obviously, if you already have a matrix structure you could use a similar approach directly filling the individual elements of the matrix. To just store certain elements or their coordinate, you could just replace the `std::copy_n()` function by something which conditionally calls a method with the corresponding coordinates, e.g.,

```
template <typename InIt, typename Predicate, typename Fun>
void filter_n(InIt it, int n, Predicate pred, Fun fun) {
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i, ++it) {
        if (pred(*it)) {
            fun(*it, i);
        }
    }
}
```

... and then replace the `std::copy_n()` with a suitable call to this function, e.g.,

```
    filter_n(std::istream_iterator<double>(in), columns,
             [threshold](double d){ return d < threshold; },
             [r](double, int c) { std::cout << "(" << r << ", " << c << ")\n"; });
```

This would just print the coordinate of the elements which are smaller than the `threshold` but it should be easy to store these coordinates and possibly the value at the position into a suitable container.

Comment: The “ragged” array you give as an initial example isn't a matrix in the mathematical sense unless the missing elements in the first three rows are implicitly zero.

Comment: @Emmet: actually, the data isn't ragged at all: the first line contains the number of rows (3) and the number of columns (4). The data follows on the 3 lines and each line contains 4 elements although they are not nicely aligned but rather written as they are quite likely to appear if a program just dumps them out, separated by a space.